# Согласовывать ли?

Tags: согласование

Вообще, такого вопроса у меня бы не возникло, но увидев в одном из официальных документов такую формулировку, я засомневалась.

**Схема разрабатывается *на основании и в соответствии* со следующими нормативно-правовыми актами.**

Я против такого построения, поскольку "на основании" и "в соответствии" по-разному согласуются с общими для них "нормативно-правовыми актами". 
Как бы вы сформулировали?

Answer (score 1):

Схема разрабатывается в соответствии со следующими нормативно-правовыми актами. Слова "на основании" являются лишними, так как "в соответствии" предполагает "основание"